# Issue In Parsing Float Value From a String in C

Tags: c

Suppose there is a string which I want to parse in C.
For parsing I want to use the function `sscanf()`.

Now, at a point, in the string there is a floating type number which may extend to a large value (before/after decimal) and sometimes less. Basically it means that the width of the number is variable.

for example,

the number can be 15.5686, 15.5686778887 or 156.867788

Let's take such strings

```
Str1 = "Hello15.5686World"
Str1 = "Hello15.5686778887World"
```

During run time any of the above strings may have to be parsed.

The starting point of the number is, however, fixed but we have no idea where does it end. So, what is the method to determine the same so that "World" (sub-string after the number)may be parsed or read properly.

Comment: You'll have to narrow down the possible inputs. 1) What floating-point format can the number be in? Is it only decimal, or also hex? 2) Can the non-numerical part of the string contain digits?

Comment: If we can know the maximum width the number can span then we can fix its starting/end points. But, this will always use that amount of space each time the string have to be parsed no matter how big or small the number is.

Comment: @EOF: Yes, the non-numerical part may contain digits.

Comment: In that case, your problem is ill-defined.

Comment: Can it contain digits without any other character in between your wanted number and random digit in non-numerical part?

Comment: Let's say for example "Hello15.5686(non-numerical part digit)world"

Comment: There can be anything before or after the floating number. There can be a digit or character.

Comment: `sscanf(Str1 + 5 /* strlen("hello") */, "%lf%s", &num, substring);`

Comment: I tried this out,

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num;
    char substring[6];
    char *Str1 = "Hello15.5686World";
    
    sscanf(Str1 + 5 /* strlen("Hello") */, "%lf%s", &num, substring);
    
    printf("%lf %s\n", num, substring);
}

Output: 

-0.000000 World

Comment: `float num;` --> `double num;` (remove part of `/* strlen("hello") */`, this is comment)

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Now, suppose there is a number in place of "Hello". 
The string supposedly may be "123415.5686567World", where the number which I am interested in is 15.5686, that is from 4th position to 12th position in the string (char array). What can be done in this case?

Comment: In such case `sscanf` can not be parsed. I think that   there is a need to check match to the three of the pattern.

Comment: @Anand `156.867788` typo as `15.56867788` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses strpbrk to find the decimal in the string.
The `no` pointer iterates toward the start of the string to find the digits preceding the decimal. If all the characters preceding the decimal are digits, then the first four characters are assumed to be the leading string.
The `s` pointer iterates toward the end of the string to find the digits following the decimal. If all the characters following the decimal are digits, then the last six characters are assumed to be the trailing string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void)
{
    //char str[] = { "abc123def98.76543zyc098"};
    char str[] = { "123498.76543123456"};
    char *leading = NULL;
    char *trailing = NULL;
    char *no = NULL;
    char *s = NULL;
    char *decimal = NULL;
    double value;

    if ( ( decimal = strpbrk ( str, ".")) != NULL) {//find the decimal
        s = decimal;//for trailing string
        no = decimal;//for start of numeric value
        while ( no > str) {//stop at start of str
            no--;//iterate toward start
            if ( !isdigit ( *no)) {
                no++;
                break;
            }
        }
        while ( *s) {//stop at '\0'
            s++;//iterate toward end of str
            if ( !isdigit ( *s)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( no == str) {//all digits
            no = str + 4;//first four characters will belong to leading
            if ( no >= decimal) {
                printf ( "problem with leading string\n");
                exit ( 1);
            }
        }
        if ( *s == '\0') {//all digits
            s = s - 6;//last six characters will belong to trailing
            if ( s <= decimal) {
                printf ( "problem with trailing string\n");
                exit ( 1);
            }
        }

        if ( ( trailing = malloc ( strlen ( s) + 1)) == NULL) {
            printf ( "malloc problem\n");
            exit ( 1);
        }

        if ( ( leading = malloc ( ( no - str) + 1)) == NULL) {
            free ( trailing);
            printf ( "malloc problem\n");
            exit ( 1);
        }

        memcpy ( trailing, s, strlen ( s));
        trailing[strlen ( s)] = '\0';

        memcpy ( leading, str, no - str);
        leading[no - str] = '\0';

        *s = '\0';//for the next sscanf terminate no at s

        if ( ( sscanf ( no, "%lf", &value)) != 1) {
            free ( leading);
            free ( trailing);
            printf ( "sscanf problem\n");
            exit ( 1);
        }


        printf ( "leading %s\n", leading);
        printf ( "value %f\n", value);
        printf ( "trailing %s\n", trailing);


    }
    else {
        printf ( "no decimal found\n");
    }

    free ( leading);
    free ( trailing);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's, till now, working according to my requirement. I will keep trying different input. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strtod` family of functions to parse the string. You can pass a pointer to a pointer to character to `strtod`, after parsing a number, that pointer then points to the rest of the string:

```
const char *Str1 = "Hello15.5686World", *endptr;
double num = strtod(Str1 + strlen("Hello"), &endptr);

printf("number: %f, rest of string: %s\n", num, endptr);
```

Comment: Considering that the OP says the non-numerical part can contain digits, the sequence `"H0xello15.5686World"` may not return what the OP is expecting. Also, `strtod()` will fail in this case, because `'H'` is neither whitespace nor a hex/decimal character.

Comment: @EOF OP said: “The starting point of the number is, however, fixed but we have no idea where does it end.” So it's just a matter of passing the beginning of the number to `strtol`.